# GRSecurity/PaX Preventing me from using TOR

Tags: tor, grsecurity

So, while trying to open the Tor Browser Bundle while using the Grsecurity with Pax enabled it returns this error:

```
./start-tor-browser: line 368:  1848 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) TOR_CONTROL_PASSWD=${TOR_CONTROL_PASSWD} ./firefox --class "Tor Browser" -profile TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default "${@}" < /dev/null
```

It works when I use the default kernel though. Also, I'm using Arch if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to use this fix that is reported at [`tor-browser-en(AUR)`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/tor-browser-en/?comments=all):

`setfattr -n user.pax.flags -v m "${INSTALL_DIRECTORY}/Browser/firefox`

Add this inside the `update()` function and you are good to go.